# How to set a title for a context menu?

Tags: android

When I bring up the context menu on a contact in the Android built-in app, the context menu has a title (the contact's name). Same for playlist context menu in the Music app.

I have added a context menu to an ImageView (no list item). There is no title, just the options are shown. Is there an easy way to set a title so that my context menu looks like the built-in apps' ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [setHeaderTitle(CharSequence  title)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html#setHeaderTitle%28int%29).